# Make an element centred when it is alone, but aligned to the right when with another element

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout

We have a page that ordinarily has two elements arranged side-by-side. Despite exploring a few angles for this, we can't seem to make it work. We're not averse to using JavaScript, it just feels that a CSS based solution ought to be possible. Is there a way of using just CSS (and possibly extra markup if necessary) to make `element2` centre when it appears on its own?

## Examples

Sometimes we have two elements, side by side.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element1">content</div>
  <div id="element2">content</div>
</div>
```

But in some conditions only `element2` is on the page e.g.:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element2">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pure css solution, however it won't work in versions of IE less than 7 because it won't understand the sibling selector (+), for that you may want to consider a JavaScript solution (perhaps Dean Edwards' [IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/)). Anyway, some example css:

```
div#element2{
  width:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
div#element1{
  width:50px;
  float:left;
}
div#element1 + div#element2{
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}
```

The key is the line div#element1 + div#element2 which selects div#element2 given that it directly follows div#element1.

Comment: Ah, great thinking! This might well be the closest solution with just css. Clever use of the pseudo selector I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Phil was on the right track, but you should try using the CSS `last-child` pseudo-class.  As far as I know, `first-child` and `last-child` are the only way in CSS to approximate an `if` construct.

```
div#container div#element2:last-child {
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

div#element1{
    width:50px;
    float:left;
}

div##element2{
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
```

The CSS above basically says "if element2 is the last child element of its parent use this set of styles, otherwise use these other styles.

This should even work in IE7.

Comment: My method should work in IE7 too, however both methods fail in IE6. It's a matter of personal preference which one is chosen, but good alternative.

Comment: D'oh!  I stopped testing for IE6.  *embarassed*  :)

Comment: Actually, I just looked this up, and last-child is from CSS2.  It should work in IE6.  What version of IE are they on now anyway?  Can someone check?  I should post this as a question on... oh, yeah.

Comment: There are hardly any pseudoclasses that work in IE6! We're lucky we can do hover styles on links (you can't on any other element)!

The current released version of IE is 7 and 8 is in beta 2, however, there are still a fair few IE6 users out there refusing to change.

Comment: Hey bill, thanks for the suggestion, I think it's a pretty good way to tackle this question too. Regarding compatibility, I think you'll find IE6 only supports :link :hover :visited and :active.

Answer (score 0):

A strict CSS2 solution:

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
}
#element1, #element2 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The inner elements should layout like inline text inside #container, but remain blocks inside.

This is standard CSS, but getting browser support might take [some trickery](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/).

Answer (score 0):

it's not cool solution becouse tables are not "trendy" anymore but it solves the problem completly (under all ie)

```
<style>
    #container {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100px;
    }

    #container table{
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #element1{ 
        background-color:#0000ff;
    }

    #element2 {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>

<div id=container>
    <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr>
            <td id="element1">content</td>
            <td id="element2">content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```